# CloudKit, NSPredicate to return a count or determine if any records exists , in a private container?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nspredicate, cloudkit

I've been researching how to determine is any RecordType records exists in a Private Container, perhaps from a previous app installation or from another device in the users iCloud account.

I see that you can not perform an NSPredicate count of records.

However I can't find an alternative to find if `any` records exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get a count.

If you wish to determine if there are any records for a given record type, perform a `CKQueryOperation` for the given record type. Set the query's predicate to `[NSPredicate predicateWithValue:YES]` and set the operation's `resultLimit` to `1`.

Then check the results. You'll either get one row back if there are any records or you'll get no rows back (or possible an error, see what happens).